# How can I write this sed script?

Tags: bash, unix, sed

Reads input number "n" and writes 0 1 ... n to the output by "n" times, separate by spaces. 
For example: n=3
1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: sed is not easy to work with for arithmetic. Why sed?

Comment: Though not articulated as such, this seems like a good question to learn two parts of `sed`find/replace -- recursion and replication. Basically, this would require a sequence of `sed 's/9/8 9/' | sed 's/8/7 8/   .... | sed 's/2/ 1 2/'` and then another `sed` replacement to repeat the pattern based on the last digit. I haven't quite got the repeat n times working yet though...

Comment: `awk -v n=3 'BEGIN{for (i=1;i<=n;i++) for (j=1;j<=n; j++) printf "%d ", j}'`

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this could be improved, but I have a `sed` solution for one-digit numbers:

```
h; # put count in holding space
s/9/8 9/ # replace 9 with 8 9
s/8/7 8/ # and so on ...
s/7/6 7/ # ensuring that the pattern space
s/6/5 6/ # ends up as 1 ... n
s/5/4 5/
s/4/3 4/
s/3/2 3/
s/2/1 2/
p # print pattern space
x # exchange pattern and hold space
/9/{s/9/8/;x;p;x} # replace 9 with 8
/8/{s/8/7/;x;p;x} # and so on ...
/7/{s/7/6/;x;p;x} # effectively counting down
/6/{s/6/5/;x;p;x} # exchanging, printing and exchanging
/5/{s/5/4/;x;p;x} # each time
/4/{s/4/3/;x;p;x} # so that the pattern space
/3/{s/3/2/;x;p;x} # is printed n times
/2/{s/2/1/;x;p;x}
/1/d # we have reached one, we're done
```

Comment: This would be a **MUCH** better answer if you explained how it works.

Comment: Top half: This replaces each number with a pair containing the number and it's predecessor (similar to my comment on your question). Thus *9* becomes  *8 9*, then *8* becomes *7 8 9*... Bottom half (ingenious IMHO) repeats the pattern n times.